# Equivalent of "ctx.save() / ctx.restore()" for PIXI.Graphics?

Tags: javascript, canvas, pixi.js

In canvas context, we can use save/restore to achieve undo/restore function, then how to save/restore the drawing states in PIXI.js, as the canvas save/restore function.
thanks

Comment: You can use native save\restore avoid PIXI, should work fine. PIXI is only wrapper above native canvas

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to ditch the default WebGL renderer and use the canvas renderer, you can use the save/restore functions as you wish - PixiJS simply wraps a canvas element, so it's still there to use as you wish.

If you want the speed, filters, etc. of WebGL, you'll need to implement your own change stack & management code.  WebGL doesn't have an equivalent to that functionality to my knowledge.